# QML progress bar is not updating smoothly

Tags: qml, pyside, qt-quick

I want to update my progress bar every 5 ms to get smooth looking decrasing progress bar. I created timer and progres bar. Problem is that my progres bar looks like it is "jumping" from 100-80-60-40-20, nothing smooth.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 840
    minimumHeight: 600

    property real prgVal1: 100

    Timer {
        interval: 5
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: root.updateProgress()
    }

    function updateProgress() {
        if (root.prgVal1 > 0)
            root.prgVal1 -= 0.1
        else
            root.prgVal1 = 100
    }

    ProgressBar {
        visible: true
        width: 120
        height: 40
        x: 20
        y: 50
        value: root.prgVal1
        from: 0
        to: 100
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?
Gif can be seen here: https://ibb.co/Wk4w2bn

Comment: `ProgressBar` cannot automatically identify the maximum and minimum value. To set a range, use the `from` and `to` properties; by default, it is between **0** and **1**. (For example, `from: 0; to: 100`).

Comment: Thanks! Now proressbar Works, but: it looks like it jumps like that: 100/80/60/40/20/0 .No smooth steps. I added console.log for prgVal1 and it really changes one by one from 100 to 0. It should update progress bar every 10 ms .

Comment: I believe *10ms* to be a very low amount; it is equal to *100Hz* (100 fps).
Change the value to *16* or *33* for a more human eye observable frame rate.

Comment: unfortunatelly it is not a solution, I changed to 10 fps (100 ms) and still it jumps roughly the same. Maybe after changing progress value call some function for update all QML visual componnets?

Comment: I feel it is fairly smooth, but you may try with decreasing the value by 0.1 steps. (e.g. `prgVal1 -= 0.1` | [Preview gif](https://ibb.co/XzDjNWt))

Comment: not for me: this is -0.1, with -1 it is the same, now period is 100 ms - but also the same as for 1 ms: https://ibb.co/Wk4w2bn

Comment: Why don't you just use some animation instead of reinventing things?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue caused by your hardware but rather by the operating system. Because you didn't specify a specific style in your application it will pick up the native style of your OS, this is why it works on Ubuntu and not on Windows. The native Windows style of the QQuickProgressBar for some reason only updates in multiple of 5%. I couldn't find the related location in the code to share here.

You can work around the issue by using a different [style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html) by default like `QtQuick.Controls.Universal`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 240

    Timer {
        interval: 5
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            if (progressBar.value > 0)
                progressBar.value -= 0.1
            else
                progressBar.value = 100
        }
    }

    ProgressBar {
        id: progressBar
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 120
        height: 80
        from: 0
        to: 100
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, in the meantime I remade my app to Pyside2 - there is not problem with progress bar. Now I changed it again to Pyside6 to try your solution. But before I added anything from your code. The progress bar is smooth also with Pyside6... Have no idea why..

Comment: I didn't use Pyside at all. It happens with a default C++ and QML application with the native style on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just use already existing components, instead of reinventing the things. Think declarative not imperative.

All you need is assign the value, nothing more. The `Timer` here is for example only.

```js
ProgressBar {
    id: progressBar
    width: parent.width * 0.8
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    from: 0
    to: 100
    value: 0
    Behavior on value {
        PropertyAnimation { duration: 300; easing.type: Easing.OutBack }
    }
}

Timer {
    interval: 1000;
    running: true;
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        var val = Math.floor(Math.random() * (progressBar.to - progressBar.from + 1) + progressBar.from);
        progressBar.value = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but not wise form that. Still do not understand why my solution does not work - it should is not it?

Comment: not ... ehm, wise? of course, I don't pretend to be a brilliant solution, but at least this code does exactly what you need. but I understand your direction. in any case, I wish you good luck in finding a truly ingenious solution.

Comment: ... If I understand, you have to generate random val, because when I set always const= 0 and want to animate to 100 it will not work? It looks like that to me...

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: Original answers deleted]

@WITC okay, I have installed pyside6 (it appears to be based on Qt6.3.0) on Ubuntu 20 and used the following Python to start my application.

```py
# main.py
import sys
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load('main.qml')
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then I did small changes to your QML program so that I can capture all the image frames I'm seeing to keyframe PNGs.

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls 6.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 840
    minimumHeight: 600

    property real prgVal1:100
    property int count: 0

    Frame {
        id: frame
        background: Rectangle {
           color: "white"
           border.color: "black"
        }
        ProgressBar {
            id: progressBar1
            visible: true
            implicitWidth: 120
            implicitHeight: 40
            value: prgVal1
            from:0
            to: 100
        }
    }

    function step() {
        frame.grabToImage(function (res) {
            res.saveToFile(`/tmp/img/grab${count}.png`);
            count++;
            if (prgVal1 >= 1.0) {
                prgVal1 -= 1.0;
                Qt.callLater(step);
                return;
            }
        } );
    }

    Component.onCompleted: step()
}
```

For combining the above image frames into an animated GIF, I used `ffmpeg` as follows:

```bash
# mkanim.sh
ffmpeg -y -framerate 20 -i '/tmp/img/grab%d.png'  -vf fps=20,palettegen /tmp/img/pal.png
ffmpeg -y -framerate 20 -i '/tmp/img/grab%d.png' -i /tmp/img/pal.png -lavfi "fps=20 [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" anim.gif
```

You note that the animation I get is smooth.

[image: pyside6-animation]

Comment: Interesting, but result is the same, Timer has 100 ms period now, in callback I decrease prgVal = prgVal-1 GIF here: https://ibb.co/27hnSHp

Comment: Thanks for trying. I am going to check again tonight. I cannot see it, but, I can only assume there is a default step property of some kind that controls the frequency in which the component is updated.

Comment: If it works for you, the problem is probably in version of Qt? I use my qml code along with Pyside6...

Comment: @WITC as per above, I reran the answer under Ubuntu 20 and pyside6. It appears that I am using Qt6.3.0.

Comment: Thank you again :-). But still does not work... Your code on my windows: https://ibb.co/RHRcyZQ

Comment: I tried it on my friends PC (Ubuntu) and there it works great, On my Windows 10, i7, 16 Gb RAM it does not work